# Where I can find "Developing Applications for SharePoint 2013" patterns & practices guide?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm reading the "Developing Applications for SharePoint 2010" guide, and it is really very useful book. but where I can find **"Developing Applications for SharePoint 2013"** patterns & practices guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2013 I believe http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12438.community-best-practices-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx this article is what currently available.

Also check this https://spg.codeplex.com/discussions/432464

Comment: what is this, as I can see, it is collection for administration and congratulation best practices for SP 2013, but I'm asking about "Developing Applications for SharePoint 2013", it is about Developing  not administration

Comment: If you read the second link Pattern and Practice is not going to release a similar book as 2010.

Answer (score -1):

There is a book called "**Microsoft SharePoint 2013 App Development**". It is available on Google books. It is also available on various online E-Commerce sites like books.rediff.com, flipcart.com, infibeam.com,etc. you can buy that book from any of the site.

Comment: there is a lot of books for development, but I'm asking about  patterns & practices book

Comment: you can find pattens & practices https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/wiki

Comment: do you know what is the Microsoft "patterns & practices"?! check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx